# How to set this php soap header?

Tags: php, soap, header

How do i set this php Soap Header ?? For the life of me I can't figure it out.

```
   <soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:HeaderOne soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
        <wsse:UsernameKey wsu:Id="tun-12345">
            <wsse:Username>myusername</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password>mypassword</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameKey>
    </wsse:HeaderOne>
   </soapenv:Header>
```

Thanks guys !

Comment: Are you using the PHP soapclient?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See this comment:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.setsoapheaders.php#93460

So it would be like:

```
$headerbody = array('UsernameKey'=>array('Username'=>$UserID,
                                         'Password'=>$Pwd)); 
$header = new SoapHeader($ns, 'RequestorCredentials', $headerbody);       

//set the Headers of Soap Client.
$soap_client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
```

Comment: Two questions:
1. What's in `$ns`?
2. Where that `'RequestorCredentials'` come from?

Comment: @pilat Check the link in the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot It helped me as well too !